# any way to disregard organizers schedule in graphapi findmeetingtimes? and all day meeting bug?

Tags: calendar, exchangewebservices, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-api

Any way to disregard organizers schedule in findmeetingtimes and is there a bug where findmeetingtimes is not observing all day meetings?

I am trying to find out if room1 is available 4/20/2018 between 8am-9am

I am trying this json body, but getting unexpected suggestions.

```
    {
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": admin@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",

      },
      "type": "Required"
    }
  ],
  "timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2018-04-20T08:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2018-04-20T09:00:00",
          "timeZone": "Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "locationConstraint": {
    "isRequired": "false",
    "suggestLocation": "true",
    "locations": [
      {
        "displayName": "room1",
        "locationEmailAddress": "room1@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H"
}
```

I get this:

```
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
"emptySuggestionsReason": "OrganizerUnavailable",
"meetingTimeSuggestions": []
```

}

Also, I it's returning that rooms are free that are booked for all day meetings on that day.

And, finally, I get organizer unavailable always on the weekends.

Answer (score 1):

> > And, finally, I get organizer unavailable always on the weekends.

For this one you don't seem to specifying an activitydomain in your timeConstraint in the request so the default would be work which means only the work hours would be considered in the response. I would suggest you try "activityDomain":"unrestricted" . Also you might want to try the Beta namespace as well as you maybe hitting a bug/feature that has been fixed in a later iteration.

Comment: thanks, missed that and this helped. But there does seem to be a but with All Day events even in Beta.

Answer (score 0):

You can disregard the organizers schedule by adding the `"isOrganizerOptional": true` to your JSON body.